# react native lazy initial state from asyncstorage

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I try to get a string from asyncStorage and set it as initial state in a functional component.
I found in the documentation that we can provide a function like initial state. I tried some solutions with asyncStorage and sqlite and don't get results. This is some code, What is wrong and is there some other solution for storing active theme in storage.

```js
const retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("theme");
    return value;
  } catch (error) {}
};

const [isTheme, setIsTheme] = useState(retrieveData);

useEffect(() => {
  AsyncStorage.setItem("theme", isTheme);
}, [isTheme]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think retrieveData is still a promise. You should get the value by doing await(retrieveData)